# How can I pass a subclass as an argument for a method that wants the super class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, arguments

I want to be able to pass a Parrot (or any other animal) object into the method addAnimal(Animal animal). I know I could add animals to the array list directly from the constructor, but there will be other animals added later that will not be in the constructor. Hence, the public method.

How can I allow all kinds of animals to be passed as arguments?

**Edited to fix constructor and basic syntax issues. The problem still exists.

```
class Zoo extends Animal{
  private ArrayList<Animal> animals;

  public Zoo {
    Parrot parrot = new Parrot();
    animals.addAnimal(parrot);      // cannot find methodaddAnimal(parrot)
  }

  public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
    animals.add(animal);
  }
}

class Animal {
  // variables and methods
}

class Parrot extends Animal {
  // variables and methods
}
```

Comment: You can't write `animals.addAnimal(parrot)` in the middle of a class definition. That sort of instruction needs to be inside a method. Also your `Parrot` class extends `animal` instead of `Animal`.

Comment: Are you asking why this code doesn't compile? You forgot a semi-colon after the list declaration. And you put code directly in the class that can only exist in a method. And ArrayList doesn't have an addAnimal method, only an add method. Even when all that is fixed, it will fail at runtime since your list is null.

Comment: Sorry guys, I tried to copy a small portion of my source over here and I didn't do a very good job. I am going to edit and add a proper constructor for Parrot and fix some syntax issues. There are not any syntax errors in my actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to invoke `ArrayList` object's `addAnimal()` method which DOES NOT exist, rather you need to invoke `addAnimal()` of the `Zoo` class object as shown in the below code with comments:

```
class Zoo {

    private ArrayList<Animal> animals;

    //create a main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Zoo zoo = new Zoo();//Create Zoo object
       Parrot parrot = new Parrot();
       zoo.addAnimal(parrot);//add parraot to list by calling addAnimal
    }

   public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
     animals.add(animal);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Zoo {
    private List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
        animals.add(animal);
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
        zoo.addAnimal(new Parrot());
    }
}

class Animal {
    // variables and methods
}

class Parrot extends Animal {
    // variables and methods
}
```